# Slider menu make elements outside not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Let's say I have this slider menu:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/alifarah/pen/VwwGypa

How can I prevent an onclick event (preventing the click happening) when the slider is active/out?

Comment: You were "forced" to add a snippet by [SO] because you're asking for help here. The general concept around this community is not about helping you, but about helping ***everyone** with a similar problem to yours* while helping you. Which means your question needs to remain relevant even after you have deleted the codepen. External links are welcome, as long as understanding (and answering) the question does not depend on them, especially when the problem can easily be reproduced here. As a sidenote, nobody is forcing you to do anything. You're free as a bird.

Comment: can you help me andrei?please see this for my exact problem!

Comment: https://recordit.co/Bp7pBhECMF

Comment: @bobcat, yes, I can help you but I'm not willing to unless you provide a sign you understood the logic behind the requirement of having a relevant snippet in the question itself and also that nobody is forcing you to do anything. If anything, we're trying to help you, along with as many others as possible. And by "we" I mean a bunch of other developers just like you, some more experienced than others. I do not represent Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to add a full-height, full-width div that blocks everything except your sliding menu to prevent the user from interacting with the rest of the page.

```
div#clickBlock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

You can add this in your `openNav` click handler and remove it within `closeNav`.

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/batzlerg/pen/oNNPpQY)